# Microcontroller Bit Operations or Something Else?

Tags: c++, microcontroller, nrf52

Using an NRF52840 (flexible 2.4GHz SoC for bluetooth and WiFi) I have a question about some code in a sample provided by the manufacturer of this SoC. I was trying to understand the following code. I think it might be some bit operations but nothing I have used before. "|" can be bit operation and "" I have only used for newline character.

```
#define _RADIO_SHORTS_COMMON \ 
(RADIO_SHORTS_READY_START_Msk | RADIO_SHORTS_END_DISABLE_Msk | \
 RADIO_SHORTS_ADDRESS_RSSISTART_Msk | \
 RADIO_SHORTS_DISABLED_RSSISTOP_Msk)
```

Comment: `\ ` is for continuing lines, especially important for macros (`#define`). Bitwise OR `¦` combines flags to one binary number. It is used to store several flags at once.

Comment: I am a little embarrassed; thank you!

Comment: Don't be. You are welcome.